# while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) or declare int ch = getchar() in advance

Tags: c

I am following the book "C Primer Plus" and encounter such a snippet of code:

```
// echo_eof.c -- repeats input to end of file.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);

    return 0;
}
```

it output:

```
$ ./a.out
She walks in beauty, like the night
She walks in beauty, like the night
   Of cloudless, climes and starry skies...
   Of cloudless, climes and starry skies...
            Lord Byron
            Lord Byron
^D
```

Nonetheless, I found that nested parentheses within `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` does not appeal to the eye.So, I changed it as:

```
// echo_eof.c -- repeats input to end of file.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ch = getchar();

    while (ch!= EOF)
        putchar(ch);

    return 0;
}
```

However, it out infinite S

```
$ ./a.out
She walks in beauty, like the night
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.....
```

What's the problem with my refactored code?

Comment: `ch` does not change after `ch = getchar();`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, the `while` condition is evaluated before every proposed iteration of the loop.  In your first code, that includes calling the `getchar()` function, plus both assigning its result to `ch` and comparing it to the macro `EOF`.  In your second code, that involves only comparing the previously-determined value of `ch` to the macro `EOF`, without reading any new input or changing the value stored in `ch`.

Comment: You can always `do { ch = getchar(); } while (ch != EOF);` if you know you will loop at least once. (though you would have to include an `if (ch != EOF) putchar (ch);` if you were outputting from the same loop). You may not "*like*" the way the parens look -- but they do have a purpose `:)`

Comment: Another possibility is `int ch = getchar(); while (ch != EOF) { putchar (ch); getchar (ch); }`

Comment: "Does not appeal to the eye" -- And yet it works, it's simple, it's solid, and it's maintainable. You need to retrain your eye. It sees wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only getting char once, BEFORE the while loop.
The char pointer never increments, so it never reaches EOF.

Just out of curiosity, have you been working with other languages like Python where methods are easily assigned to variables?
It's a bit trickier in C, you need to use pointers:

```
int (*ch)(); // Creates a function pointer
ch = getchar; //Then assign your getchar() function to it, without the brackets
while ((*ch)() != EOF) // Dereference and call your function
```

Comment: The snippet you give doesn’t work to print the input to terminal.

Comment: Not really the point, just demonstrating how to assign a function to a variable.
 
The OP is new to C and appears to be trying to apply ideas that would be standard in something like Python, so next time they think "I want to assign this function to a function pointer" they know how.